# $X(G)=4$ then G contains $K_4$

Tags: graph-theory

This is a practice question in my text.

Its a true and false question and I have to prove it its true $X(G)=4$ then G contains $K_4$ where $X(G)$ is the chromatic number. I know this is true but how do I prove this. I have found a answer online http://book.huihoo.com/pdf/graph-theory-With-applications/pdf/chapter8.pdf

but the proof here is to complicated for me. Please note this is for a first course in Graph theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference you found shows that a 4-chromatic graph contains a *subdivision* of $K_4$, not that it has $K_4$ as a subgraph.

What's the chromatic number of

[image]

Does it contain a $K_4$?

Comment: @AndrewSalmon The corresponding result for chromatic number $5$ is equivalent to the $4$-color theorem. For $\chi = 4$, it's a lot easier.

Comment: nope it doesnt. Not sure why I didn't see this before. Thanks, May I know how you made the graph.

Comment: @KjTada I drew it with TikZ.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually false.  In fact, Erdős proved that there exist graphs of arbitrarily high girth (the length of the smallest cycle) and chromatic number using a probabilistic method.

For something that doesn't use probabilistic methods, you can recursively construct graphs of $\chi(G)$ arbitrarily large that don't even contain $K_3$ (their girth is $\ge 4$).  See, for example, the [Mycielski construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian).